# MariaDB spatial query to determine proportion of overlap

Tags: mariadb, spatial-query

Background: I have two tables containing geometries (polygons and multipolygons). One table contains large polygons that touch but do not overlap (they are actually administrative boundaries). The other contains smaller polygons (in this case, they are parcels of land).

In most cases, each smaller polygon from the second table will be wholly contained within one of the larger polygons from the first table. This is simple enough to determine with spatial queries (ST_WITHIN). Some, however, will overlap two (or, theoretically, more) admin area polygons.

The question is, for those smaller polygons which overlap two large ones, how can I tell which it is most in?

This image illustrates the situation. Land parcel A is wholly within Leftshire, and B is wholly within Rightshire. This is a simple ST_WITHIN spatial query. I can determine that C overlaps both Leftshire and Rightshire as ST_WITHIN will be false but ST_OVERLAP will be true for both of them. But how can I determine that C is more in Leftshire than it is in Rightshire?

[image]

For reference, I am using MariaDB 5.5.64. If the problem is more easily solved using a different version (or even using a different DB), that would be an acceptable fallback, but I would ideally like to solve it using the tools I have to hand if possible.

[Edit: One simple solution would be to check which larger area the centroid of the smaller area falls into. This would work perfectly for rectangles, as in the example. However, it will not be reliable where the shapes are more complex, and I need this to work even for complex multipolygons as neither administrative areas nor land parcels are reliably simple in real life!]

Comment: Why don't you compare ST_AREA? e,g, `SELECT(ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(leftshire, my_area)) > ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(rightshire, myarea))`

Comment: That, indeed, does sound like it might well be the answer.

Comment: Having finally got round to testing it, that does work as intended. Thank you.